# error with updating user information firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

so i am creating a sign up page and connect that with firebase users

i am recieving error with updating profile

my code goes as follow:

for creating new user i use

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.v("SignUp", "222222222222222222222222222");
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "SignUp failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.v("SignUp", "333333333333333333333333333");
                            uploadImage();

                        }
                    }
                });
```

and the uploadImage() method is

```
public void uploadImage() {
    if (image != null) {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference main = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("link to my account");
        StorageReference storageReference = main.child("images/" + image.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(image);

        //addonFailurelistener too

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.v("SignUp", "777777777777777777777777");
                String download = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();


                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .build();
                //i tried here with .setDisplayName(name)
                //and with setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(download)

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.v("SignUp", "8888888888888888888888888888");
                            addDatabase();
                        } else {

                       FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Log.v("SignUp", "999999999999999999999999999");
                                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Error Occuered While setting your account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, SignUp.class));
                                    } else {
                                        Log.v("SignUp", "..........................");
                                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Error Cannot be resolved \n please try with another Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

and my logcat get output like that

```
V/SignUp: 333333333333333333333333333
V/SignUp: 777777777777777777777777
V/SignUp: ..........................
```

i followed the firebase guide but looks like i am doing something wrong

any idea why it doesnt work? thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat if you're getting error?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get it automatically resolved after waiting for 24 hours so  i am assuming account get blocked for 24h after some number of logIn in a single day